# Keyboard doesn't show with KeyboardAvoidingView in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I would like to know how can I use the keyboard with React Native.

When I click in my input (on "Send"), I don't have a Keyboard show.

[image]

I tried to use "KeyboardAvoidingView" but the Keyboard doesn't show.

> ChatScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MessageList from './MessageList';
import MessageForm from './MessageForm';

export default class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
                <MessageList />
                <MessageForm />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
    },
});
```

> MessageForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import MessageFormStyles from './MessageFormStyles'

export default class MessageForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={MessageFormStyles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={MessageFormStyles.input}
                    placeholder="Send">

                </TextInput>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

> Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "expo": "31.0.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "6.0.1",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

Do you have an idea why I don't see the Keyboard ?

Comment: are you using simulator or real device?

Comment: @CuongTranDuc I use the simulator (xCode)

Comment: try command + shift + k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a simulator then the keyboard must be disabled in your simulator hardware settings.

Please go and toggle the keyboard and you might see the keyboard again